# Limit on the number of topics in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a particular usecase where I might need a very large number of topics in kafka. Essentially this is for timeseries and hence would like to get a general understanding how should I approach this.

I know that theoretically there is no limit, but practically there will be some limits. Would like to get some expert opinion here.

Is it possible to scale to a million topics for instance or even higher?

Comment: You should specify how many brokers you plan on deploying... How much data in total... Topics amount alone isn't enough info. "time series" also doesn't justify more than one topic, so it's not clear what you're actually asking for

Answer (score 14):

Well, there is no fixed numbers defined for topics/partitions on a cluster. But definitely there are some best practices which depicts howto scale the cluster in efficient way.

Actually number of topics itself really not determine the scalability of a cluster. No. of partitions affects more instead of number of topics. Each topic can have one or multiple partitions. The more number of partitions you have, more file handles will be open and that will affect the latency.  Also more partitions increase the unavailability.

So when you do Cluster size and capacity planning, follow the below rule for stable cluster.

> As a rule of thumb, if you care about latency, it’s probably a good
> idea to limit the number of partitions per broker to 100 x b x r,
> where b is the number of brokers in a Kafka cluster and r is the
> replication factor.

Here is nice blog post by confluent:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster

Personally I have experienced problem with 5600 topics/23000 partitions ob 6 Broker nodes cluster. And brokers became unavailable due to huge open file handles and we had to scale the cluster to 12 nodes.

**Update:**

As Kafka has got plently of improvements over time, now it can support over 200K partitions.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-supports-200k-partitions-per-cluster/

Comment: So more brokers means more partitions (100 * B) but how does increasing replicas R result in a linear scaling of topics (100 * B * R)? Maybe 1/R?

Comment: @RickO'Shea  not OP so just a guess but perhaps the relationship stems from the fact that producers write directly to a partition, whereas consumers read from the broker?  That is until Kafka 2.4, where it's now possible for consumers to read directly from a partition (under specific config settings)

Comment: Good to mention that the blog by Confluent referred to in this answer dates from 2015 and that in the meantime there have been improvements to Kafka which allows for a greater number of partitions one Kafka cluster is able to support. See this newer post: https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-supports-200k-partitions-per-cluster/

Comment: Let's say that I have 2000 topics (on a three broker cluster) with one partition per topic. Would having more number of topics add significant resource and management overhead on Kafka? We need dedicated topics for data segregation and security standpoint hence can not go with multiple partition approach.

Comment: Well, number of topics should be decided on based on the data type and granularity you have. If data can't be stored in partitions but has to be indepentent topic, that would be the approach.